# Index of the first occurence of each value in a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector and I want to get the location (indices) of the first occurrence of each unique value.

```
vec <- c(4,4,4,3,3,3,5,4,5,4,3,3,56)
(pos <- ?????????)
```

I want in return

```
# 1  4  7  13
```

I.e. `1` is the first index of 4, `4` is the first index of 3, and so on.

Comment: See `?duplicated`; `which(!duplicated(vec))`

Comment: @alexis_laz Thats the answer i want to accept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to @Pratik's approach

You can use `match` along with `unique`

```
match(unique(vec), vec)

#[1]  1  4  7 13
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code should do the trick for you:

```
vec <- c(4,4,4,3,3,3,5,4,5,4,3,3,56)

firstUniqueOccurrence <- function(vec) {
    unq <- unique(vec)
    sapply(unq, function(x) {min(which(vec == x))})
}

firstUniqueOccurrence(vec)

[1]  1  4  7 13
```

Answer (score 2):

As per you your vector element, try using the below command to get the desired output.

```
match(c(4,3,5,56), vec)
```